# int 0801 "out of range"

Tags: java, eclipse, int

Ok so I have an enum class that contains information like below:

```
...
_08_01(811, "08_01"),
....
```

I am wanting to change the int 811 to 0801 to match enum, but when I do, eclipse throws me an error saying:

```
The literal 0801 of type int is out of range
```

I can't figure out what it is out of range of, as it definitely isn't int range.  Can anyone help me understand why this is being thrown?

Thanks!

Comment: 0 preceding will make the number interpreted as octal number. And 8 is not an octal digit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number starting with 0 is in octal base and you can't use the digit '8' in it.

Answer (score 2):

The literal 0801 is octal (the 0 in front indicates that). This means that 8 is not allowed in there.

Answer (score 1):

ints that start with 0 are treated as Octal (not decimal)